# List of clients connected to Virtual Adhoc

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network

I have an adhoc set up via command prompt using 'netsh ....'. I want to view the names of devices connected to it. I have tried arp -a but it only provides me with physical IP address of the device connected. I want to view the name too. For eg: if 'XYZ-PC' is connected to my adhoc I want to be able to view from an cmd command that the name of the device connected is 'XYZ-PC' . Is there any attribute I have to apply to arp to do that? Or is there another method altogether. Thanks in Advance

Comment: That would probably be very difficult, because IIRC it’s a mesh network, there’s probably no node that maintains direct connections to all other nodes.

Answer (score -1):

net view on windows

C:\Users\CUBE>net view /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET VIEW
[\computername [/CACHE] | [/ALL] | /DOMAIN[:domainname]]

Comment: Not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.